# How to speed up this script in PyQGIS?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, performance, azimuth

I am a new in PyQGIS, I want to create a Point layer from a raster layer. In table of point layer created, there is 3 fields by name of "X_coord", "Y_coord" and "Azimuth", each point in Point layer shows x ("X_coord" field), y ("Y_coord") center coordinate of each pixel from raster layer and "Azimuth" field shows azimuth from another single point layer to each center pixels. When I run this script for raster layer with 67*52 pixels in 30 meter resolution time for running is 5 seconds, for 133*105 pixels time is 15 seconds and for 291*220 pixels time is 22 minutes!
I think this is unusual.How can I decrease time for run this script for large data?

My script is:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from osgeo import gdal
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import time

startTime = time.clock()

pnt = QgsVectorLayer(r'E:/Sample_Dataset_Lorestan/Point.shp', 'POINT','ogr')
for feat in pnt.getFeatures():
   geom = feat.geometry()
   pntxy=geom.asPoint()

# Open tif file
ds = gdal.Open(r'E:\Sample_Dataset_Lorestan\subset_a1.tif')

numpy_array = ds.ReadAsArray()
# GDAL affine transform parameters

geotransform = ds.GetGeoTransform()
originX = geotransform[0]
originY = geotransform[3]
rotationX = geotransform[2]
rotationY = geotransform[4]
pixelWidth = geotransform[1]
pixelHeight = geotransform[5]

cols=ds.RasterXSize
rows=ds.RasterYSize

def pixel2coord(x, y):
   xp =  (pixelWidth * x) + originX + (pixelWidth/2)
   yp =  (pixelHeight * y) + originY + (pixelHeight /2)
   return(xp, yp)

#Create temporary vector layer and add to map
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=", "temporary_points", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
# Add points:
pr = vl.dataProvider()
# Enter editing mode
vl.startEditing()
# add fields
pr.addAttributes( [ QgsField("X_coord", QVariant.Int), QgsField("Y_coord", QVariant.Int), QgsField("Azimuth", QVariant.Int) ] )

# add a feature
fet = QgsFeature()

# get columns and rows of your image from gdalinfo

for row in range(0,rows):
   for col in range(0,cols):
    rspnt = pixel2coord(col,row)
    rspnt2 = QgsPoint(rspnt[0], rspnt[1])
    fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(rspnt2))
    fet.initAttributes(3)
    fet.setAttribute(0, rspnt[0] )
    fet.setAttribute(1, rspnt[1])

    az = pntxy.azimuth(rspnt2)
    if az < 0.0:
         azim = 360 + az
    else:
        azim = az

    fet.setAttribute(2, azim)
    pr.addFeatures( [fet] )

# Commit changes
vl.commitChanges()
print "completed within:", time.clock() - startTime, "seconds", "\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version (modified from gene's response):

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=", "temporary_points2", "memory")
vl.dataProvider().addAttributes([ QgsField("X_coord", QVariant.Int), QgsField("Y_coord", QVariant.Int), QgsField("Azimuth", QVariant.Int) ])

new_features = []
for row in range(0,rows):
   for col in range(0,cols):
      rspnt = pixel2coord(col,row)
      fet = QgsFeature()
      fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(rspnt[0], rspnt[1])))
      fet.initAttributes(3)
      fet.setAttribute(0, rspnt[0] )
      fet.setAttribute(1, rspnt[1])
      az = pntxy.azimuth(QgsPoint(rspnt[0], rspnt[1]))
      if az < 0.0:
         azim = 360 + az
      else:
         azim = az
      fet.setAttribute(2, azim)
      new_features.append(fet)

vl.dataProvider().addFeatures( new_features )
vl.updateExtents()
vl.updateFields()    
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([vl])
```

This version only calls `addFeatures` once, rather than once per pixel in the loop.

Update:
Here's a version to try to avoid the memory errors from storing everything in a single list. Now, the features are added once per row. It's not as fast as the above method, but less memory hungry:

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=", "temporary_points2", "memory")
vl.dataProvider().addAttributes([ QgsField("X_coord", QVariant.Int), QgsField("Y_coord", QVariant.Int), QgsField("Azimuth", QVariant.Int) ])

for row in range(0,rows):
   new_features = []
   for col in range(0,cols):
      rspnt = pixel2coord(col,row)
      fet = QgsFeature()
      fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(rspnt[0], rspnt[1])))
      fet.initAttributes(3)
      fet.setAttribute(0, rspnt[0] )
      fet.setAttribute(1, rspnt[1])
      az = pntxy.azimuth(QgsPoint(rspnt[0], rspnt[1]))
      if az < 0.0:
         azim = 360 + az
      else:
         azim = az
      fet.setAttribute(2, azim)
      new_features.append(fet)

   vl.dataProvider().addFeatures( new_features )
vl.updateExtents()
vl.updateFields()    
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([vl])
```

Comment: Hi ndawson, you are a professional programmer, It's work very well, for 291*220 pixels, time change from 5 minutes to 8 seconds, for 418*326 pixels time is 14 seconds, It's very good,but when I want to run for 10393* 7170 pixels layer below error appear!!!!                                            Traceback (most recent call last):........... new_features.append(fet)    MemoryError.           what's happend!!?

Comment: Try the updated version

Comment: I used updated version, first time without any error, closed QGIS program, in second time, after 1 minute, appeared an "Exception  window" with "bad allocation" message!! Is this relation to my Computer? My system is win 8.1 64bit, RAM 4 GB, Core i7 2.2 GHz. I installed QGIS 2.12.3 Lyon from OSGeo4W.

Comment: Ok, revision posted

Comment: Hi ndawson, I run two times your revision posted, but after 3 minutes, without any error closed QGIS program!

Comment: A solution is to use generators in place of lists. Generators are iterables, but you can only read them once. It's because they do not store all the values in memory, they generate the values on the fly - > `ds = (Point((s * x) + originX + (s/2), (s2 * y) + originY + (s2/2))  for x in range(colums) for y in range(rows))` is a generator for Shapely, for example, and you can use it with Fiona to create shapefiles with very big files without problem.

Comment: Hi gene, thanks for your solution but I don't want to use Fiona, I believe pyqgis and gdal have potential for solve this problem!

Answer (score 4):

1) If your pnt shapefile has only one element, use the iterator method [next()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```py
feat = pnt.getFeatures().next()
pntxy = feat.geometry().asPoint()
```

If the shapefile has many elements, use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
pntxy = [feat.geometry().asPoint() for feat in pnt.getFeatures()]
# select pntxy[0] or pntxy[1] or...
```

2) instead of GDAL, why don't you use  directly PyQGIS ?

```py
ds = QgsRasterLayer('E:\Sample_Dataset_Lorestan\subset_a1.tif','subset_a1')
pixelWidth = ds.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
pixelHeight = ds.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()
# extent of the layer
ext = ds.extent()
originX ,originY  = (ext.xMinimum(),ext.yMinimum())
cols = ds.width()
rows = ds.height()
```

3) memory layer in the Python console (no need of `vl.startEditing()`)

```py
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=", "temporary_points2", "memory")
vl.dataProvider().addAttributes([ QgsField("X_coord", QVariant.Int), QgsField("Y_coord", QVariant.Int), QgsField("Azimuth", QVariant.Int) ])
fet = QgsFeature()
for row in range(0,rows):
   for col in range(0,cols):
      rspnt = pixel2coord(col,row)
      fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(rspnt[0], rspnt[1])))
      fet.initAttributes(3)
      fet.setAttribute(0, rspnt[0] )
      fet.setAttribute(1, rspnt[1])
      az = pntxy.azimuth(QgsPoint(rspnt[0], rspnt[1]))
      if az < 0.0:
         azim = 360 + az
      else:
         azim = az
      fet.setAttribute(2, azim)
      vl.dataProvider().addFeatures( [fet] )
      vl.updateExtents()
      vl.updateFields()

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([vl])
```

Comment: That's great job, very thanks gene, new code change time of run for 291*220 pixels from 22 minutes to 5 minutes!!! But my main raster layer is 10393* 7170 pixels, It is important to reduce this time again. can I do another changes for receive lower time of run? Thanks.

Comment: You can use [Fiona](http://toblerity.github.com/fiona/manual.html) and [Rasterio](https://github.com/sgillies/rasterio) in Python only without PyQGIS (faster)

Comment: Try moving the `vl.updateExtents()` and `vl.updateFields()` out of the loop. They don't need to be called multiple times.

Comment: Another good optimisation would be not calling `vl.dataProvider().addFeatures()` for every single feature. Instead, add them all to a list and only call addFeatures once for the whole list.

Comment: Sorry ndawson, moving the vl.updateExtents() and vl.updateFields() out of the loop increased time of run from 298.7 seconds to 307.4 seconds for 291*220 pixels, for second of your suggestion I can't understand because I add them in [fet], can u correct this section? Thanks,

Comment: Well, in your current code you are adding a list of 1 feature for every pixel. Instead, add ALL the pixel features to a list and call addFeatures ONCE with the entire list of features. So 1 call to addFeatures, rather than 1000s.

Comment: Hi ndawson, I think you're right, sorry but I am new in pyqgis, can you write correct code, Thanks.